# position charts on html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im building a basic dashboard and using google charts to do so.
I have successfully embedded my gauge charts on the webpage. I am now trying to position them.

I have read that this needs to be done using `css positioning`.

My question is if this is the solution , how can I use this within my code.

Im trying to split, so I will have 3 gauges on top and 2 underneath..

I have tried using `<div style = "position:relative; left:?; top:?px </div>` in differant positions but I cant get it to work..

```
<html>
    <body style="background-color:dodgerblue;"></body>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Daily GP', 80],
          ['MTD GP', 55],
          ['Open RO', 68],
          ['NPS', 68],
          ['Charging Eff', 68]
        ]);
        
        var options = {
          width: 800, height: 200,
          greenFrom: 90, redTo: 60,
          yellowFrom:60, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
        
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 13000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 5000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(2, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(3, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(4, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
        
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 200px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just style your chart_div with CSS using `position: absolute;` and then position it using the `top` and `left` properties. For example:

With positioning:

```css
#chart_div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="background-color:dodgerblue;"></body>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['gauge']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Daily GP', 80],
        ['MTD GP', 55],
        ['Open RO', 68],
        ['NPS', 68],
        ['Charging Eff', 68]
      ]);

      var options = {
        width: 800,
        height: 200,
        greenFrom: 90,
        redTo: 60,
        yellowFrom: 60,
        yellowTo: 90,
        minorTicks: 5
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);

      setInterval(function() {
        data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }, 13000);
      setInterval(function() {
        data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }, 5000);
      setInterval(function() {
        data.setValue(2, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }, 26000);
      setInterval(function() {
        data.setValue(3, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }, 26000);
      setInterval(function() {
        data.setValue(4, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }, 26000);

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 200px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Without positioning:

```html
<html>
    <body style="background-color:dodgerblue;"></body>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Daily GP', 80],
          ['MTD GP', 55],
          ['Open RO', 68],
          ['NPS', 68],
          ['Charging Eff', 68]
        ]);
        
        var options = {
          width: 800, height: 200,
          greenFrom: 90, redTo: 60,
          yellowFrom:60, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
        
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 13000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 5000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(2, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(3, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(4, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
        
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 200px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want three gauges on top and three gauges on the bottom, the way I would do it, is place them each in their own div and wrap them in a flexbox container! I've detached the data into two different divs, each with their own id (`top-row` && `bottom-row`). Then I assign the `Document.getElementById()` to find both of them and write the gauges that I want to them.
Flexbox allows us to, essentially, wrap the content within the container!

```html
<html>

<body style=" background-color:dodgerblue;">
</body>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['gauge'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            var topData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Label', 'Value'],
                ['Daily GP', 80],
                ['MTD GP', 55],
                ['Open RO', 68],
                ['NPS', 68],
                ['Charging Eff', 68]
            ]);
            var bottomData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Label', 'Value'],
                ['Some Jazz', 80],
                ['Open RO', 68],
            ]);

            var options = {
                width: 800, height: 200,
                greenFrom: 90, redTo: 60,
                yellowFrom: 60, yellowTo: 90,
                minorTicks: 5
            };

            var topCharts = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('top-row'));
            var bottomCharts = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('bottom-row'))
            topCharts.draw(topData, options);
            bottomCharts.draw(bottomData, options)
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gauge-container" style="display: flex; flex-wrap:wrap">
        <div id="top-row" style="width: 800px; height: 200px;"></div>
        <div id="bottom-row" style="width: 800px; height: 200px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```